# jquery: mouseover not working properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mouseover

please open this site

http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/security/

and go with the mouse at in the bottom of the site, you'll see 3 images with title

now try and go over with the mouse to the title and it suppose to show red box. I have problem with the last title. When i go to the last title the jQuery script doesn't work and i have no idea why so can you guys see and help me what am i doing wrong?

here is the code:

```
<?php  
     $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
     $recentPosts->query('showposts=3');
?>
<?php 
     while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="box">
      <div class="slice">
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?></div>
<script>
  jQuery('.titlebox1').hover(function()
  {
  jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeIn(500);
  jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeOut(500);
  },function()
  {
  jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeOut(500);
  jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeIn(500);
  });
 </script>

<div class="titlebox1">
  <h3 class="titlebox"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div class="posttext"> 
       <h3 class="date"><?php the_time('M d, Y') ?></h3>
         <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are appending the script for the hoverbox 3 times. Here the HTML for a single box :

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="slice"><img width="339" height="332" src="http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/security/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/n2.png" class="attachment- wp-post-image" alt="n2"></div>
        <script>
            jQuery('.titlebox1').hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeIn(500);
            jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeOut(500);
            },function(){
            jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeOut(500);
            jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeIn(500);
            });

        </script>
        <div class="titlebox1"><h3 class="titlebox" style="display: block;"><a href="http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/security/why-do-we-use-it-2/">Why do we use it?</a></h3>
            <div class="posttext" style="display: none;"> 
                <h3 class="date">May 22, 2014</h3>
                <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be… </p>
                <p> <a href="http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/security/why-do-we-use-it-2/">LÆS MERE</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, you have a script tag. This script is appended 3 time, which is bad, but not the problem here. The script is there before the `titlebox1`. So in order, when the first script is added, it bind an event on nothing. The second time, it bind on the first and the third time, it bind on the first and the second.

So at the end, the `box 1` has 2 events, the `box 2` has 1 event and lastly `box 3` has none.

Put you code in the head and add a DOM ready handler :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.titlebox1').hover(function()
  {
  jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeIn(500);
  jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeOut(500);
  },function()
  {
  jQuery(this).find('.posttext').fadeOut(500);
  jQuery(this).find('.titlebox').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please guide me on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394371/add-javascript-in-wordpress-functions-php-with-wp-enqueue-script/36395004?noredirect=1#comment60407943_36395004  As it is similar to this one ..