# Add Javascript in Wordpress - functions.php with wp_enqueue_script()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to add my custom javascript to my wordpress page.

I tried it usign `wp_enqueue_script()` but its not working. When I tried to add script directly in Inspect element it works properly so my script is correct.

Now I create function in `function.php` file to add script and its not working. It shows script / file is loaded in page when I check source of page. But it doing nothing.

Below is my script and function.

Javascript -

```
jQuery(".tp-tab").mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery('.tp-tab').removeClass("selected");
});
jQuery(".tp-tab").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Function in function.php

```
    function mytheme_custom_scripts() {

            if ( !is_admin() ) {
                $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/themes/circles/js/';
                wp_register_script( 'myhandle', $scriptsrc . 'slider_hover_effect.js', 'jquery', '1.0',  false );
                wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle' );
            }

        }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts' );
```

In `/wp-content/themes/circles/js/` directory location my script is palced with file name of `slider_hover_effect.js` which contain above javascript code.

Please let me know is there any other way I can add this script in my wordpress website. Also I want to add/apply this script only for Homepage. So is this possible.

Thanks,

### Update

I am not sure about that I should provide complete path after `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` or just `/js/` folder.

Or

Can I use like -

```
function slider_effect() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(".tp-tab").mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery('.tp-tab').removeClass("selected");
});
jQuery(".tp-tab").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
});

    </script>

    <?php

}

add_action('wp_head','slider_effect');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your functions.php

```
function mytheme_custom_scripts(){
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page()) {
            $scriptSrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider_hover_effect.js';
            wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle', $scriptSrc , array(), '1.0',  false );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts' );
```

JavaScript file (slider_hover_effect.js)

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {
    $( 'body' ).on( 'mouseenter', '.tp-tab', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.tp-tab', function () {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

1. Check if there is any error in browser console.
2. View page source and see if the file is included at the bottom of source.
3. There might be some precedence issue, to check that try to change 'false' parameter to 'true' in wp_enqueue_script function (so the script will be added to header).

I hope this helps.

Comment: All your checklist is properly working. Script file is loading and there is no error in console. still script is not working.

Comment: Can you put console.log(123); after "$(function() {" and see if 123 is there in the console?

Comment: I tried to print some text in JS script on Page and it working. But my code is not working . The effects I want to add is based on slider classes. When I inspect element those class shows but not in pagesource

Comment: But, if you open page source is this file (slider_hover_effect.js) is available there? Note: if you added is_home condition view page source of homepage.

Comment: I've also added is_front_page() condition to the function. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes my  JS file is available in Source, Also added in footer then also available. Code is working when I directly add on Inspect element and there is no error.

Comment: Text at Logo is print on page. But events are not working

Comment: As I understood, your tab elements will be dynamic that's why the current event doesn't triggers. Try to update the Js file.

Comment: I tried using above code still events are not working. I replace   function line with this `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".logo").html("erthgfhfghf adafdsfwretred");` and it shows text instead of logo but events not working. with your function line nothing shows.

Comment: It works fine but it has some delay in actions to effect. But its fine now. Is there anything we can improve in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,change `!is_admin()` with `is_home()`

```
 function mytheme_custom_scripts() {
          if ( is_home() ) {
                    $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle', $scriptsrc . 'slider_hover_effect.js', array(), '1.0',  false );
           }
     }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts' );
```

or:

```
function slider_effect() {
if ( is_home() ) {
 ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(".tp-tab").mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery('.tp-tab').removeClass("selected");
});
jQuery(".tp-tab").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
});
});
    </script>

    <?php }

}

add_action('wp_head','slider_effect');
```

Comment: Are you sure about `/js/` file location? Should I use same or provide complete path for it. Or Can I use it Directly in function is `<script></script>`

Comment: you are asking us lol you know where you put the script you should know the path

Comment: I know where is my file. I am asking should I provide complete path or just `/js/` like this.

Comment: your file should be in /themename/js/slider_hover_effect.js go with a browser there if the page doesn't list your script you have the wrong url

Comment: Yes my js file in js directory of theme. Check updates in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**functions.php**

```
function mytheme_custom_scripts() {
// No need to check admin, 'wp_enqueue_scripts' only enqueues at the frontend 
            $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';
            wp_register_script( 'myhandle', $scriptsrc . 'slider_hover_effect.js', array('jquery'), '1.0',  false );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle' );

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts' );
```

Check full codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script

You should not print JS in 'wp_head' unless you can't do otherwise.

**slider_hover_effect.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".tp-tab").mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).removeClass("selected");
   });
   $(".tp-tab").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("selected");
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about `/js/` file location? Should I use same or provide complete path for it. Or Can I use it Directly in function is `<script></script>`

Comment: You don't have to use complete path @RahulDambare.
Plz check again if its working, its a **well tested code**.

Comment: I check with your code .. and also check Source of page js file is loaded in source. But code is still not working. Should I use `$` instead of `jQuery` word in js file .. Please check updates in question

Comment: First check if the file is added to the page now.
You also might want to wrap your jquery in `JQuery(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: can you please addcomplete  jQuery code if possible.

Comment: Have you found your solution @RahulDambare ?
Yeah, updated `JQuery` to `jQuery`

Comment: Not Yet Leo. Its still not working. Trying to do with all solutions here

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot the src parameter in the `wp_enqueue_script` when you called it in your callback `mytheme_custom_scripts`

From wordpress docs:

```
wp_enqueue_script ( string $handle, string|bool $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Parameters

$handle
(string) (Required) Name of the script.

$src
(string|bool) (Optional) Path to the script from the root directory of WordPress. Example: '/js/myscript.js'.
Default value: false

So I believe your code should be:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle' , $scriptsrc . 'slider_hover_effect.js');
```

---

Another way is if you can create your custom plugin and activate that plugin to allow you to include custom js or css like this in your index.php file of the plugin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script' );

function my_script() {
    if( is_home() ){
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script', plugins_url('js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__));
    }
}
```

You place the files in the js/ or css/ dir and this works

Comment: I dont know how to implement this code in plugin. As this is just a small code I want to prefer it to write in fuctions.php file. Can you please provide proper code